# Insert custom content before widget title/after widget opening tag

Tags: widgets

I am trying to target a widget with a specific class, and place something directly after the opening tag or before the widget title.

This:

```
<widget>
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>Some content goes here...</p>
</widget>
```

Becomes:

```
<widget>
<!-- Custom content or element goes here -->
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>Some content goes here...</p>
</widget>
```

I can't quite hook into it, I do not want to use css, this needs to be added with widget logic in order to be user-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter:

```
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 
    function( $params )
    {
       // target a sidebar id:
       if( isset( $params[0]['id'] ) && 'sidebar-1' === $params[0]['id']
       {    
           // target a widget name:
           if( isset( $params[0]['widget_name'] ) && 'Text' === $params[0]['widget_name'] )
           {
               // target a widget id:
               if( isset( $params[0]['widget_id'] ) && 'text-8' === $params[0]['widget_id'] )
               {
                   // Append text to existing 'before widget' markup code:
                   if( isset( $params[0]['before_widget'] ) )
                   { 
                       $params[0]['before_widget'] .= '<!-- Custom content -->';
                   }
               }
            }
         }
         return $params;
    } 
);
```

where the widget names are for example: *Text*, *Categories*, *Calendar*, ... .

You can then modify it to your needs, for example the `'sidebar-1'`, `'Text'` and `'text-8'` parts.

Comment: Thank you ever so much, that work like a charm!

It's necessary to use class instead of id as I'd need multiple widgets with this purpose.
Is it a simple case of changing **widget_id** to **widget_class**?

Thank you again for such a fast and detailed response!

Comment: Ooh no worries! I removed the targeting of widget name and widget id :)